backgroundInteractionEnabled={true} prop is not working fine
Issue: Inability to Scroll Map with backgroundInteractionEnabled
Description: I’m encountering an issue with the backgroundInteractionEnabled prop in the react-native-actions-sheet package. While setting backgroundInteractionEnabled={true} does work as expected—showing a difference in the backdrop opacity between defaultOverlayOpacity values of 1 and 0. I am still unable to scroll the map beneath the sheet.
problem screen record
Steps to Reproduce:
Implement a MapScreen with an ActionSheet overlaid on top.
Set backgroundInteractionEnabled={true} for the ActionSheet.
Observe that although the backdrop opacity changes, the map beneath the sheet remains unscrollable.
Expected Behavior: The map beneath the ActionSheet should be scrollable even when the sheet is open, without needing to close the sheet.
Observed Behavior: Despite setting backgroundInteractionEnabled={true}, I can’t scroll the map underneath the ActionSheet. The only way to interact with the map is to close the ActionSheet.
Questions:
Is this an issue with my code implementation or a potential bug in the react-native-actions-sheet package?
Are there any additional configurations or workarounds that can resolve this issue?
Code Snippet:
My map-route-detail-sheet.tsx file:
// map-route-detail-sheet
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {Alert, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import ActionSheet, {
  ActionSheetRef,
  FlatList,
  SheetManager,
  SheetProps,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native-actions-sheet';
import {
  View,
  Button,
  Text,
  Icon,
  Carousel,
  DistanceIndicator,
  ExpandableCard,
} from '../../components';
import LocationService from '../../services/location-service';
import Theme from '../../theme';
import {LogService} from '../../services/log-service';

function MapRouteDetailSheet(props: SheetProps<'map-route-detail-sheet'>) {
  const actionSheetRef = useRef<ActionSheetRef>(null);
  const selectedPost = props.payload!.selectedPost;
  const navigation = props.payload!.navigation;
  const onClose = props.payload!.onClose;

  const [expandIndex, setExpandIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(0);
  const images =
    selectedPost?.waypoints
      ?.flatMap(w => w.places.flatMap(p => p.images?.map(i => i.url) || []))
      .filter((url): url is string => url !== undefined) || [];
  const days = selectedPost?.waypoints || [];
  let places = days[selectedDay]?.places || [];

  //   LogService.debug('MapRouteDetailSheet', selectedPost.waypoints![0].places[0]);

  const openGoogleMaps = async () => {
    const locationService = LocationService.getInstance({
      postId: selectedPost._id,
    });
    await locationService.openGoogleMaps(places);
  };

  return (
    <ActionSheet
      id={props.sheetId}
      ref={actionSheetRef}
      containerStyle={{
        borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
        borderTopRightRadius: 25,
      }}
      indicatorStyle={{
        width: 100,
      }}
      snapPoints={[20, 30, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]}
      initialSnapIndex={4}
      statusBarTranslucent
      closeOnPressBack
      enableGesturesInScrollView={true}
      drawUnderStatusBar={true}
      gestureEnabled={true}
      closeOnTouchBackdrop={false}
      onClose={onClose}
      backgroundInteractionEnabled={true}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View marginH-20 marginT-20 gap-10>
          <Text>{selectedPost.title}</Text>

          <Carousel imgList={images} />
          <Text h5>{selectedPost.content}</Text>

          <View spread>
            <View marginT-20>
              <Text h1 sb black>
                {'Rota Durakları'}
              </Text>
              <FlatList
                horizontal
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                data={days}
                renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                  <Button
                    key={index}
                    label={item.day + '. Gün'}
                    size="small"
                    outline={selectedDay !== index}
                    paddingV-10
                    paddingH-20
                    marginV-4
                    marginR-12
                    onPress={() => setSelectedDay(index)}
                  />
                )}
              />
              <View marginT-8 />
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={openGoogleMaps}>
                <View bg-gray5 row center gap-8 style={styles.mapsButton}>
                  <Icon name="GoogleMaps" size={28} />
                  <Text h5 sb>
                    {'Yol Tarifi Al'}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <View marginT-8 />

              {/* Route Destinations expandable container */}
              {places.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <View>
                    <ExpandableCard
                      data={item}
                      expanded={expandIndex === index}
                      navigation={navigation}
                      onPress={() =>
                        expandIndex === index
                          ? setExpandIndex(-1)
                          : setExpandIndex(index)
                      }
                    />
                    {index !== places.length - 1 && (
                      <DistanceIndicator showTransportIcon={false} />
                    )}
                  </View>
                );
              })}
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.footer} />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </ActionSheet>
  );
}

export default MapRouteDetailSheet;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  footer: {
    height: 100,
  },
  mapsButton: {
    padding: 4,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: Theme.colors.gray2,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
});


and my MapScreen.tsx file:
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Alert,
  Image,
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useMemo, useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {PostType, ScreenProps} from '../types';
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';
import Geolocation, {
  GeolocationResponse,
} from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import {LogService} from '../services/log-service';
import LocationService from '../services/location-service';
import Theme from '../theme';
import {View} from '../components';
import {MapModel} from '../utils/models';
import {SheetManager} from 'react-native-actions-sheet';

const defaultLocation = {
  latitude: 38.720489,
  longitude: 35.482597,
  latitudeDelta: 0.01,
  longitudeDelta: 0.01,
};
const origin = {latitude: 38.720489, longitude: 35.482597};
const destination = {latitude: 38.690518, longitude: 35.5576858};

export default function MapScreen({
  navigation,
  route,
}: ScreenProps<'MapScreen'>) {
  const {posts} = MapModel();
  const [userLocationLoading, setUserLocationLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState<
    GeolocationResponse | undefined
  >(undefined);
  const animation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const mapRef = useRef<MapView>(null);

  const getCurrentPosition = async () => {
    setUserLocationLoading(true);
    const locationService = LocationService.getInstance({postId: 'MapsScreen'});

    try {
      if (!userLocation) {
        const location = await locationService.getCurrentPosition(
          (coords: any) => {
            if (coords) {
              LogService.debug('Current Position', coords);
            } else {
              LogService.error('No coordinates returned');
              Alert.alert('Error', 'Unable to fetch location.');
            }
          },
        );

        if (location) {
          setUserLocation(location);
          // Zoom to user location when first fetched
          if (mapRef.current) {
            mapRef.current.animateToRegion(
              {
                latitude: location.coords.latitude,
                longitude: location.coords.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: 0.1,
                longitudeDelta: 0.1,
              },
              1000,
            ); // 1000 ms for smooth animation
          }
        } else {
          LogService.error('No location returned');
        }
      } else {
        // If location already fetched, just animate to it
        if (mapRef.current) {
          mapRef.current.animateToRegion(
            {
              latitude: userLocation.coords.latitude,
              longitude: userLocation.coords.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: 0.1,
              longitudeDelta: 0.1,
            },
            1000,
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      LogService.error('Error fetching location', error);
    } finally {
      setUserLocationLoading(false);
      LogService.info('Location fetching process completed.');
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentPosition();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const renderMarkers = useMemo(() => {
    if (posts.length === 0 || userLocationLoading) {
      return null;
    }
    return posts.map((p, index) => (
      <Marker
        key={index}
        coordinate={{
          latitude: p.waypoints![0]?.places[0]?.location?.lat!,
          longitude: p.waypoints![0]?.places[0]?.location?.lng!,
        }}
        draggable={false}
        onPress={() => {
          setShowRoutePlaces(true);
          SheetManager.show('map-route-detail-sheet', {
            payload: {
              selectedPost: p,
              navigation: navigation,
              onClose: () => setShowRoutePlaces(false),
            },
          });
        }}>
        <View>
          <View
            width={60}
            height={60}
            bg-primary
            center
            style={{
              borderRadius: 100,
              borderColor: Theme.colors.black,
            }}>
            <Image
              width={50}
              height={50}
              source={{uri: p.waypoints![0]?.places[0]?.images![0].url}}
              style={{borderRadius: 100}}
              resizeMode="cover"
            />
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              alignItems: 'center',
              marginTop: 4, // Adjust as needed to place the needle correctly
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </Marker>
    ));
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [posts]);

  const renderDirection = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <MapViewDirections
        origin={origin}
        destination={destination}
        apikey={process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY!}
      />
    );
  }, []);

  const [showRoutePlaces, setShowRoutePlaces] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        onMapLoaded={() => LogService.info('Map loaded')}
        provider="google"
        style={styles.map}
        mapType={'terrain'}
        userInterfaceStyle={'dark'}
        initialRegion={defaultLocation}>
        {showRoutePlaces ? renderDirection : renderMarkers}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});


I trying remove position of 'absolute' style on MapScreen and nothing changed i think problem can caused on package:
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Alert,
  Image,
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useMemo, useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {PostType, ScreenProps} from '../types';
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';
import Geolocation, {
  GeolocationResponse,
} from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import {LogService} from '../services/log-service';
import LocationService from '../services/location-service';
import Theme from '../theme';
import {View} from '../components';
import {MapModel} from '../utils/models';
import {SheetManager} from 'react-native-actions-sheet';

const defaultLocation = {
  latitude: 38.720489,
  longitude: 35.482597,
  latitudeDelta: 0.01,
  longitudeDelta: 0.01,
};
const origin = {latitude: 38.720489, longitude: 35.482597};
const destination = {latitude: 38.690518, longitude: 35.5576858};

export default function MapScreen({
  navigation,
  route,
}: ScreenProps<'MapScreen'>) {
  const {posts} = MapModel();
  const [userLocationLoading, setUserLocationLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState<
    GeolocationResponse | undefined
  >(undefined);
  const animation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const mapRef = useRef<MapView>(null);

  const getCurrentPosition = async () => {
    setUserLocationLoading(true);
    const locationService = LocationService.getInstance({postId: 'MapsScreen'});

    try {
      if (!userLocation) {
        const location = await locationService.getCurrentPosition(
          (coords: any) => {
            if (coords) {
              LogService.debug('Current Position', coords);
            } else {
              LogService.error('No coordinates returned');
              Alert.alert('Error', 'Unable to fetch location.');
            }
          },
        );

        if (location) {
          setUserLocation(location);
          // Zoom to user location when first fetched
          if (mapRef.current) {
            mapRef.current.animateToRegion(
              {
                latitude: location.coords.latitude,
                longitude: location.coords.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: 0.1,
                longitudeDelta: 0.1,
              },
              1000,
            ); // 1000 ms for smooth animation
          }
        } else {
          LogService.error('No location returned');
        }
      } else {
        // If location already fetched, just animate to it
        if (mapRef.current) {
          mapRef.current.animateToRegion(
            {
              latitude: userLocation.coords.latitude,
              longitude: userLocation.coords.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: 0.1,
              longitudeDelta: 0.1,
            },
            1000,
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      LogService.error('Error fetching location', error);
    } finally {
      setUserLocationLoading(false);
      LogService.info('Location fetching process completed.');
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentPosition();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const renderMarkers = useMemo(() => {
    if (posts.length === 0 || userLocationLoading) {
      return null;
    }
    return posts.map((p, index) => (
      <Marker
        key={index}
        coordinate={{
          latitude: p.waypoints![0]?.places[0]?.location?.lat!,
          longitude: p.waypoints![0]?.places[0]?.location?.lng!,
        }}
        draggable={false}
        onPress={() => {
          setShowRoutePlaces(true);
          SheetManager.show('map-route-detail-sheet', {
            payload: {
              selectedPost: p,
              navigation: navigation,
              onClose: () => setShowRoutePlaces(false),
            },
          });
        }}>
        <View>
          <View
            width={60}
            height={60}
            bg-primary
            center
            style={{
              borderRadius: 100,
              borderColor: Theme.colors.black,
            }}>
            <Image
              width={50}
              height={50}
              source={{uri: p.waypoints![0]?.places[0]?.images![0].url}}
              style={{borderRadius: 100}}
              resizeMode="cover"
            />
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              alignItems: 'center',
              marginTop: 4, // Adjust as needed to place the needle correctly
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </Marker>
    ));
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [posts]);

  const renderDirection = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <MapViewDirections
        origin={origin}
        destination={destination}
        apikey={process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY!}
      />
    );
  }, []);

  const [showRoutePlaces, setShowRoutePlaces] = useState(false);

  return (
    <MapView
      ref={mapRef}
      onMapLoaded={() => LogService.info('Map loaded')}
      provider="google"
      style={{
        flex: 1,
      }}
      // style={styles.map}
      mapType={'terrain'}
      userInterfaceStyle={'dark'}
      initialRegion={defaultLocation}>
      {showRoutePlaces ? renderDirection : renderMarkers}
    </MapView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    // ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});


